# How do I make a button that verifies that I have picture in picturebox?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a form to capture company information.
I have a button to complete the registration.
I have tried to make sure the button doesn’t work, until after the user enters all the required information.
i.e. First name,company name…
Additionally the user must also load a logo of company they're registering.
I've made a picture box and coded that correctly. The problem is that I want that when I click on the button, to make sure that user enters a picture.
If the picture hasn't been loaded, then the button doesn’t work.
I tried to code it but it is not working.

```
If Not PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("gg")
End If

//The  first code

Try

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR12", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
Form2.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

Comment: How about an `If...Else...End If` block instead?  It will run the ELSE block if there is no image loaded (if `.Image` is equal to `Nothing`).

Comment: Why even let the user click the Button if the data hasn't been provided? You should disable the Button by default and then write a method that validates the form contents and sets the Button state appropriately. You can then handle the appropriate events of the other controls and call that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this:

```
If PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("No Image loaded.")
Else
    MsgBox("Image loaded.")
End If
```